# Меню с условием

Tags: php

Как лучше сделать? 
у меня есть страница index.php в ней я сделал include_once ("menu.php"); ну и ещё в трех файлах(profile.php,edit_profile.php,friends.php) мне нужно сделать условие в файле menu.php а в файле menu.php у меня обычные ссылки:

```
<a href="">Главная</a><br>
<a href="">Страница 1</a><br>
<a href="page/page2.php">Страница 2</a><br>
```

так вот нужно составить такое условие что бы при заходе на profile.php и edit_profile.php 
пункт меню "Страница 2" не отображается(не выводился).. мучаюсь немогу сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вы даете:
в скрипте сделаейте тaк:
$menu = array(
'url'=>'index.php', title="Главная"
'url'=>'page/page2', title="page2"
); 
И циклом выведите в меню.
И изменяйте этот массив на каждой странице под ваши нужды

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $forbidden = array('profile.php', 'edit_profile.php');
    $indicator = ltrim(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), '/');
    if (in_array($indicator, $forbidden, true) === false) {
?>
   <a href="page/page2.php">asd 2</a><br>
<?php } ?>
```